# Fastest way of performing bulk updates with array of objects in Node-Postgres?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql, performance

I'm working with the `pg` Postgres driver in Node.js, and was wondering what the fastest way of doing bulk updates would be. I've tried the following approach:

```
// items is an array with 5 objects containing keys code and issue.
const items = [{code: "ABC", issue: "1"}, {code: "BDC", issue: "2"}, {code: "ADE", issue: "312"} ...];
const client = await pool.connect();
try {
  await client.query("BEGIN");
  const query = "UPDATE Data SET id = $1 WHERE code = $2 AND issue = $3";
  const promises = [];
  for (const item of items) {
    promises.push(
      client.query(query, [process.env.CLIENT_USER, item["code"], item["issue"]])
    );
  }
  await Promise.all(promises);
  await client.query("COMMIT");
  // query takes 16 seconds at most, 4-5 at least.
} catch (e) {
  await client.query("ROLLBACK");
}
```

This has been quite slow, as I have been left waiting for around 16 seconds at most, and 4-5 at least (with `console.time()`). The `Data` table (has no without indexes whatsoever) consists of approx. 2 million rows and is increasing by a few 100ks per week. What could I do to make these bulk updates faster?

UPDATE:
Analyzing 1 UPDATE query gives me:

```
  {
    'QUERY PLAN': 'Update on data  (cost=0.00..66035.23 rows=1 width=132) (actual time=745.924..745.924 rows=0 loops=1)'
  },
  {
    'QUERY PLAN': '  ->  Seq Scan on data  (cost=0.00..66035.23 rows=1 width=132) (actual time=280.835..745.695 rows=1 loops=1)'
  },
  {
    'QUERY PLAN': "        Filter: ((code = 'GIME'::text) AND (issue = '1226'::text))"
  },
  { 'QUERY PLAN': '        Rows Removed by Filter: 1989938' },
  { 'QUERY PLAN': 'Planning Time: 0.086 ms' },
  { 'QUERY PLAN': 'Execution Time: 746.097 ms' }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "without indexes" ? Do you mean that you don't have an index on the column (-s) code and/or issue? And could you show us the result from EXPLAIN ANALYZE for a single UPDATE query?

Comment: @FrankHeikens Without indexes as in there are no indexes whatsoever in the Data table. And sure, I'll run it and update the question.

Comment: Without any index, the database will be slow by design. Do you know what column has the most unique values? Code or issue, and create an index on that column first.

Comment: @FrankHeikens It's currently a combination of 2 columns (code + issue) that makes each row unique. Would an index work with that? And I've now updated my post to include ANALYZE for 1 UPDATE query.

Comment: When the combination is unique and must be unique, it looks like you could use a unique index: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON data(code, issue);

Comment: @FrankHeikens I'm astonished by the results! The queries went from a few seconds minimum to a few milliseconds only. Thanks a lot!